# Django distinct on a specific field

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class A:
    name = Char...

class B:
    base = ForeignKey(A)
    value = Integer..
```

`B.objects.values('a__name','value').distinct('a__name')`

As you understand above, I try to get the B objects grouping by its related object's name. However, distinct function doesn't take parameter.

I have tried by annotation and aggregation but I couldn't group by `a__name`
I have also tried `values_list` with `flat=True` but it only takes one column name but I need both `a__name` and `value` fields.

How can I do that in Django?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need Django 1.4+. If you're running a lesser version, you're out of luck. Then, you must be using PostgreSQL. Passing a parameter to `distinct` does not work with other databases.

See the [documentation for `distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) and pay attention to the "Note" lines.

You could always issue a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), I suppose, as well, if you don't meet the above conditions.